# Alternate function of math.pow in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am using `Math.pow()` function in my code but when I try to execute below condition, this function return infinity which is not required. I am looking for an alternate solutions.

`math.pow(451939.27436410653, 299);`

Please help if anyone any idea

Comment: it's not a problem with Math.pow() but with your value. It's too big to be computed this way

Comment: You do realise that what you're trying to compute there is a *phenomenally huge* number, right? `Infinity` almost seems like a realistic answer! Google's calculator gives up, but it's a 1,690-digit long number! [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=451939.27436410653%5E299)

Comment: There are about `Math.pow(10, 82)` atoms in the observable universe. What are you counting?

Comment: The answer has nearly 1700 digits, too much for an IEEE 754 double precision floating point number to handle. Use a bignum library or another language that has bignums built in.

Comment: @DavidConrad At the risk of being pedantic, it's not the absolute number of digits but the log_2 of the value that matters :D

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol That's true, although a double only has 53 bits of mantissa, so even if it were within range there'd be a lot of precision lost.

Comment: Use jQuery, it does all things !

Comment: `299*log(451939.27436410653)` meaning there will be something like 1690 digits in the result before the decimal point.

Answer (score 2):

#### Use logs

What result were you expecting? The result is extremely large and exceeds the ability of the conventional floating point format to represent. I would be surprised if this was really necessary in a real-world calculation. Can you provide some context?

If really necessary, perhaps you could resolve the difficulties by using logarithms. If y=Math.pow(451939,299) then 
Math.log(y) = Math.log(451939) * 299.

You could do any multiplication/division by adding/subtracting logs, and then do a Math.exp at the end to generate your result.

This may be easier than using a special library like bignumber.js for arbitrary-precision arithmetic. For example, the code below returns "7.395117980030695  x 10^ 1690", which has 1691 digits before the decimal point.

```js
let log10Y=Math.log(451939.27436410653)*299/Math.log(10);
let b = Math.floor(log10Y);
let a = log10Y-b;
console.log("Answer: ",10**a," x 10^",b);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store such enormous numbers, you can use a library like [bignumber.js](https://github.com/MikeMcl/bignumber.js/). It stores floating-point values with an exponent as large as necessary to store them.

Comment: Read the documentation: "It accepts a value of type number (up to 15 significant digits only), string or BigNumber object." You can give it a string instead or just let JavaScript round off the number.